# Router : logging port traffic

Tags: router, port-forwarding, logging

I have a router Fibergateway from my ISP provider and I would like to forward a large spectrum of external ports to a single port in a computer in my intranet. Does this make any sense? Is this possible? How can I do that?

My aim is to log all the requests sent to my IP for these ports. Is it possible somehow? By other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

This likely depends on the settings available on your gateway hardware.

> How can I do that?

If the unit includes router functionality and supports port forwarding, it may be possible to simply forward the range of ports you wish to monitor to the specific internal IP/port combination you wish to have listen for these requests.

> My aim is to log all the requests sent to my IP for these ports.

The device listening for these requests might need separate software in order to do this. Depending on your needs, one suggestion I might make is to consider [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for this. Note that Wireshark can listen to multiple ports on the same network interface, so there may be no need forward requests to a single port e.g. via your gateway.

> Does this make any sense?

Without knowing why you want to do this, this is likely unanswerable. But from a technical perspective, this could be theoretically possible to do. Do note that this could "break" the functionality of certain software (ex. a web server on the internal device may not be able to connect to a port if another piece of software is connected to that port).

Comment: I tried to do that in my router, it has port forwarding and port activation. In port forwarding I can't do that. One external port corresponds to one internal port. In port activation I couldn't get the wide range I need.

Comment: The device listening to all these requests is a router from my ISP...